# Database appears locally but not when deployed to Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I am deploying an app to Heroku as part of a college project. The app deploys and loads but elements from my database do not show on Heroku. When I test the website locally (I am using Cloud 9) they show without issue.

When I run `heroku run rake db:migrate` I get the following:

```
$ heroku run rake db:migrate
Running rake db:migrate on ⬢ enigmatic-forest-86241... up, run.9158
  ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (1.9ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"
```

Apologies if this is an easy question or already answered but I could not find anything by searching.

Comment: first you have to run `heroku run rake db:create`

Comment: just to clarify, you're saying the database doesn't appear or the data that you have locally, doesn't appear on heroku?

Comment: i agree with @neydroid , the data you have locally will not appear on heroku. Also make sure you have added `pg` gem for production in your gemfile.

Comment: The response you're seeing isn't an error. That's what it says when the command runs successfully.